# Flask + uWsgi, endpoints not available over HTTPS

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I'm running a containerized flask API serving with uwsgi and nginx. Now that I am trying to add SSL to my API I'm having some issues.
According to this answer: [nginx with uwsgi and flask shows bad request for https connections only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155284/nginx-with-uwsgi-and-flask-shows-bad-request-for-https-connections-only) I should not change my uwsgi settings when I have NGINX in front of it.

I'm using flask-restplus which provides swagger. On http://domain/api/ I get my normal Swagger documentation and all my endpoints work fine. On https://domain/api/ I get an empty Swagger-page with "No API definition provided" and none of the end-points are present.

In other words, accessing my flask instance over HTTPS works fine. What I cannot figure out is how to get flask to serve my endpoints over HTTPS instead of HTTP (or preferrably, both).
There are several answers here on SO that adds a context to the `app.run()` function, but this is only valid when using flask's built-in server, which is nonesense in a prod enviornment where you need SSL.

Here's my `server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restplus import Api

from chatbot.api.v1.dialogflow import dialog_api as v1_dialog_api
from chatbot.api.v1.web import web_api as v1_web_api
from chatbot.api.v2.api import api as v2_api

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(v1_dialog_api)
app.register_blueprint(v1_web_api)

api = Api(app, version='2.1')
api.add_namespace(v2_api)

CORS(app)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are doing a reverse proxy through nginx you don't have to touch your python code at all. You should run your containerized flask API e.g. under port 22222 then use nginx to reverse proxy 22222 to 80. Then port forward the 80. Nginx can be customized extensively so it handles SSL, does automatic forwarding/redirects etc.  
The nginx reverse proxy can also be run from a docker container. 
If you code the certs into your Flask API other people may have problem running your code since they don't have the certs. Reverse proxy is done quite often but it is outside of my expertise.

Comment: There's no one else who needs to run my production server. My problem is that Flask only serves my defined end-points over HTTP. As I said, my nginx setup atm correctly serves swagger over HTTPS (which is served by my flask instance), however, there are no defined end-points for HTTPS. I cannot find any Flask documentation on how to serve endpoints to HTTPS instead of HTTP.